# DialogFlow (Can you have one master agent which controls other agents?)

Tags: dialogflow-es

Something like Angular where its modularized. Modules are a great way to organize an application and extend it with capabilities from external libraries.

Have one Master agent where its connected to different agents?

Comment: I haven't seen this done yet but I think a logical step will be to have a tool that uses the API to merge multiple agents into one.  Smaller agents are good for modularity.  Bigger agents are good for most consistently doing what users want.

Answer (score 1):

You can make multiple agents then write a script where you would call the agents using the sdk based on the condition.

Each agent would have a project id which will be used to make the connection to the agent.

Below is example how to it in python:

```
import dialogflow

def detect_intent_texts(project_id, session_id, text)
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

    session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
    text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text=text)

    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)

    response = session_client.detect_intent(
        session=session, query_input=query_input)


session_id = initialize_session_id_from_application
text = get_text_from_application

if condition == 1:
    res = detect_intent_texts(project_id_1, session_id, text)
elif condition == 2:
    res = detect_intent_texts(project_id_2, session_id, text)
else:
    res = detect_intent_texts(project_id_3, session_id, text)
```

You can view the user query using `res.query_result.query_text`, and detected intent using `res.query_result.intent.display_name`.

Do note that different intent will create different sessions internally.

Hope it helps.